# function override, returning Vector with specialized type

Tags: flash, actionscript

Is it possible to implement a Subclass, that overrides a function, which returns a Vector with specialized instances?

Example:

```
class ClassA{
    protected _vector:Vector.<DisplayObject>;

    public function get vector():Vector.<DisplayObject>{
        return _vector;
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA{

    public override function get vector():Vector.<Sprite>{
          return Vector.<Sprite>(_vector);
    }
}
```

When I try to to it like this, I get an "illegal override" error at compile time.
I think that's because the functions signatures aren't identical. 
But how can I solve this otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the main problem with a Vector class in ActionScript3. It basically prevents any form of polymorphism. You need to somehow remember what kind of objects your class returns. The easiest way isn't overriding the function, but leaving it as it is and than casting each element to a appropriate form.

Answer (score 1):

You can either have the get function return a vector of "unknown" type :

```
class ClassA
{
    protected _vector : Vector.<DisplayObject>;

    public function get vector() : Vector.<*>
    {
        return _vector;
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA
{
    public override function get vector() : Vector.<*>
    {
        return Vector.<Sprite>(_vector);
    }
}
```

Or you could return * instead of Vector.<*> both should allow you to do something like

```
var sprites : Vector.<Sprite> = classBInstance.vector;
```

and allow you to override the get function and return the type you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Your override does not make any sence to me... :)

if you want to get back the whole vector you need to use only the get vector () from ClassA,
no need to override it:

```
class ClassA{
protected _vector:Vector.<DisplayObject>;

    public function get vector():Vector.<DisplayObject>{
        return _vector;
    }
}
```

If you want to get a specific sprite from the vector ( ClassB or ClassA ):

```
public function getSprite ( id : int ) : Sprite
{           
    try
    {
        return _vector[id] as Sprite;
    }
catch ( e : Error ) {}

    return null;
}
```

If you want to get all the vector With Sprite Types ( ClassB or ClassA ):

```
public function get vectorAsSprite ():Vector.<Sprite>
{
   return Vector.<Sprite> ( _vector );
}
```

Comment: When I have an instance of ClassB, I want to get back a Vector with Sprites, yes. And Yes, I could do it with an additional function. In other languages (like java) it is possible to do it with a single function. Would be a much better coding style imho.

Comment: if you have declared your variable as `Vector.<DisplayObject>` and if you have a classA where function return value is `Vector.<DisplayObject>`, you can not override it with `Vector.<Sprite>`, because they need to be same classtypes.

Answer (score 0):

An override must have an identical function signature in AS3, so what you're proposing is not possible.

You'd need to write a separate function with a different signature that simply returns the original vector, but cast as the desired type.

This may or may not be worth the effort to you.